# Switch between views but maintain click events in Xamarin

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin

I am using a `LinearLayout` with various other layouts to act as a menu bar at the bottom of two of my AXML files in Xamarin (Android development atm).

On my main activity I have set click events to switch between two AXML views, both of which include the `LinearLayout` menu bar.

The first button click works, and switches the layout, however after that it appears none of my click events work anymore. I have tried re initializing the click events, inside the click events but to no avail.

Please consider the following code:

**Main.AXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Main Page" />

<include
    layout="@layout/menu_bar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Other.AXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/MyButton2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Other Page" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/menu_bar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.cs**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace Tracker
{
    [Activity(Label = "Tracker", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        LinearLayout newsMenuItemLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.newsMenuItem);
        LinearLayout friendsMenuItemLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.friendsMenuItem);

        newsMenuItemLayout.Click += (sender, args) =>
        {
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Other);
        };


        friendsMenuItemLayout.Click += (sender, args) =>
        {
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        };
    }
}
```

**menu_bar.AXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout03"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="75dp"
      android:weightSum="100"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/newsMenuItem"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
      <ImageView
          android:src="@drawable/news_icon"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/imageView1"
          android:scaleType="fitCenter"
          android:adjustViewBounds="false" />
      <TextView
          android:text="News"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/textView1"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/eventsMenuItem"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
      <ImageView
          android:src="@drawable/events_icon"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/imageView2"
          android:scaleType="fitCenter"
          android:adjustViewBounds="false" />
      <TextView
          android:text="Events"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/textView2"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/resultsMenuItem"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
      <ImageView
          android:src="@drawable/results_icon"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/imageView3"
          android:scaleType="fitCenter"
          android:adjustViewBounds="false" />
      <TextView
          android:text="Results"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/textView3"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/friendsMenuItem"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
      <ImageView
          android:src="@drawable/friends_icon"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/imageView4"
          android:scaleType="fitCenter"
          android:adjustViewBounds="false" />
      <TextView
          android:text="Friends"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/textView4"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/moreMenuItem"
    android:background="@drawable/selector"
    android:paddingTop="6dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
  <ImageView
      android:src="@drawable/more_icon"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/imageView5"
      android:scaleType="fitCenter"
      android:adjustViewBounds="false" />
  <TextView
      android:text="More"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/textView5"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I assume that as I am reloading my menu_bar, I need to reinitialise my click events, but how would be the best way to go about that?

I did previous load my menu bar as an `ActionBar` which I believe is a separate entity to the content view, but as this was impossible to move from the top, I had to rethink the approach.

Any ideas/explanations as to how I can go about this are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your resetting your entire content view, you can go the route of toggling the visibility of them or you can just replace the menubar itself instead of calling `SetContentView` multiple times.Essentially you would get a reference to your menuBar, get it's parent view and inflate your new layout and remove the old menuBar and add the new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why this behavior occurs however A solution could be is to include both your layouts in your main layout with one hidden. Switch visibility in the places where you use SetContentView.

**Main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <include
   android:id="@+id/FirstLayout"
   layout="@layout/first" />

 <include
   android:id="@+id/SecondLayout"
   android:visibility="gone"
   layout="@layout/second" />

 <include
   layout="@layout/menu_bar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**first.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/MyButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Main Page" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**second.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/MyButton2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Main Page" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace Tracker
{
    [Activity(Label = "Tracker", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            LinearLayout newsMenuItemLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.newsMenuItem);
            LinearLayout friendsMenuItemLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.friendsMenuItem);
            LinearLayout firstlayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.FirstLayout);
            LinearLayout secondlayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.SecondLayout);
            newsMenuItemLayout.Click += (sender, args) =>
            {
                firstlayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                secondlayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            };


            friendsMenuItemLayout.Click += (sender, args) =>
            {
                firstlayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                secondlayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great workaround, thanks very much, and I will use this for now. I will accept the answer, provided someone doesn't come up with a more 'correct' solution over the weekend. Not to say yours doesn't work :) but you know what I mean.

Comment: Yes it's a workaround. You could consider using fragments instead of layouts and handeling click events for the right layout within the fragment. That will make your main activity less cluttered. But that's up to you :)

Comment: @DanikRaikhlin +1 for just using fragments. If you're going to the effort of toggling off/on 2 layouts then you've built a rudimentary fragment system anyway. Best just to implement it with fragments.